# clipping a voronoi diagram python

Tags: python, scipy, computational-geometry, spatial, voronoi

I am computing a voronoi diagram from a set of points as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(0)
points = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (100, 2))
# Compute Voronoi
v = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(v)
plt.show()
```

This creates an image as follows:

[image: Voronoi]

As one can see, this is creating vertices which are going to infinity (dashed lines) and also beyond the original bounding box for the points which is:

```
 bbox = np.array([[-0.5, -0.5], [0.5, -0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [-0.5, 0.5]])
```

What I would like to do is clip the voronoi diagram to this bounding box i.e. project the out of bounds and infinite vertices onto the appropriate locations on this bounding box. So the vertices would need to be rearranged and projected back to the proper intersection points from infinity or the finite vertices but which are out of bounds from my clipping region.

Comment: @unutbu Although it seems true that one can obtain the answer from the link to "Colorize Voronoi Diagram" the relation is not direct or obvious from my point of view. Luca made a similar question earlier and at the time I interpreted that he wanted only vertices inside a bounding box (and my answer at the time was for that). This time he seems to want the intercept points between bounding box and infinite regions of Voronoi. Not necessarily for plot purposes. I do not consider this to be a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, what it is is to somehow have the intersection between the voronoi plane with the out of bounds and infinite vertices and the bounding box given by `[[-0.5, -0.5], [0.5, -0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [-0.5, 0.5]]`. I am not sure if the other code is doing that...I am looking at it now.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a more immediate way but check out code for intersection of two lines (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/find-the-point-of-intersecting-lines). Obviously you'll have to do it for each of the vertices that go into the infinite regions.

Comment: Just to mention that I wrote a C++ version of what you want, it is available [here](https://github.com/sloriot/cgal-voronoi-cropping). This also contains a user package for [cgal-swig-bindings](https://github.com/cgal/cgal-swig-bindings) so a python version might not be too hard to have (though I only made the effort to make it work for java).

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665491/getting-a-bounded-polygon-coordinates-from-voronoi-cells) a similar (duplicate?) question with an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a bounded polygon coordinates from Voronoi cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665491/getting-a-bounded-polygon-coordinates-from-voronoi-cells)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be easyly be done with [Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely). You can install it from Conda Forge: `conda install shapely -c conda-forge`

Code you need at [github.gist](https://gist.github.com/Sklavit/e05f0b61cb12ac781c93442fbea4fb55), based on answer by [@Gabriel and @pv.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678647/618045):

```
# coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def voronoi_finite_polygons_2d(vor, radius=None):
    """
    Reconstruct infinite voronoi regions in a 2D diagram to finite
    regions.
    Parameters
    ----------
    vor : Voronoi
        Input diagram
    radius : float, optional
        Distance to 'points at infinity'.
    Returns
    -------
    regions : list of tuples
        Indices of vertices in each revised Voronoi regions.
    vertices : list of tuples
        Coordinates for revised Voronoi vertices. Same as coordinates
        of input vertices, with 'points at infinity' appended to the
        end.
    """

    if vor.points.shape[1] != 2:
        raise ValueError("Requires 2D input")

    new_regions = []
    new_vertices = vor.vertices.tolist()

    center = vor.points.mean(axis=0)
    if radius is None:
        radius = vor.points.ptp().max()*2

    # Construct a map containing all ridges for a given point
    all_ridges = {}
    for (p1, p2), (v1, v2) in zip(vor.ridge_points, vor.ridge_vertices):
        all_ridges.setdefault(p1, []).append((p2, v1, v2))
        all_ridges.setdefault(p2, []).append((p1, v1, v2))

    # Reconstruct infinite regions
    for p1, region in enumerate(vor.point_region):
        vertices = vor.regions[region]

        if all(v >= 0 for v in vertices):
            # finite region
            new_regions.append(vertices)
            continue

        # reconstruct a non-finite region
        ridges = all_ridges[p1]
        new_region = [v for v in vertices if v >= 0]

        for p2, v1, v2 in ridges:
            if v2 < 0:
                v1, v2 = v2, v1
            if v1 >= 0:
                # finite ridge: already in the region
                continue

            # Compute the missing endpoint of an infinite ridge

            t = vor.points[p2] - vor.points[p1] # tangent
            t /= np.linalg.norm(t)
            n = np.array([-t[1], t[0]])  # normal

            midpoint = vor.points[[p1, p2]].mean(axis=0)
            direction = np.sign(np.dot(midpoint - center, n)) * n
            far_point = vor.vertices[v2] + direction * radius

            new_region.append(len(new_vertices))
            new_vertices.append(far_point.tolist())

        # sort region counterclockwise
        vs = np.asarray([new_vertices[v] for v in new_region])
        c = vs.mean(axis=0)
        angles = np.arctan2(vs[:,1] - c[1], vs[:,0] - c[0])
        new_region = np.array(new_region)[np.argsort(angles)]

        # finish
        new_regions.append(new_region.tolist())

    return new_regions, np.asarray(new_vertices)

# make up data points
np.random.seed(1234)
points = np.random.rand(15, 2)

# compute Voronoi tesselation
vor = Voronoi(points)

# plot
regions, vertices = voronoi_finite_polygons_2d(vor)

min_x = vor.min_bound[0] - 0.1
max_x = vor.max_bound[0] + 0.1
min_y = vor.min_bound[1] - 0.1
max_y = vor.max_bound[1] + 0.1

mins = np.tile((min_x, min_y), (vertices.shape[0], 1))
bounded_vertices = np.max((vertices, mins), axis=0)
maxs = np.tile((max_x, max_y), (vertices.shape[0], 1))
bounded_vertices = np.min((bounded_vertices, maxs), axis=0)



box = Polygon([[min_x, min_y], [min_x, max_y], [max_x, max_y], [max_x, min_y]])

# colorize
for region in regions:
    polygon = vertices[region]
    # Clipping polygon
    poly = Polygon(polygon)
    poly = poly.intersection(box)
    polygon = [p for p in poly.exterior.coords]

    plt.fill(*zip(*polygon), alpha=0.4)

plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'ko')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(vor.min_bound[0] - 0.1, vor.max_bound[0] + 0.1)
plt.ylim(vor.min_bound[1] - 0.1, vor.max_bound[1] + 0.1)

plt.savefig('voro.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, I struggle to understand: `t = vor.points[p2] - vor.points[p1] # tangent
            t /= np.linalg.norm(t)
            n = np.array([-t[1], t[0]])  # normal

            midpoint = vor.points[[p1, p2]].mean(axis=0)
            direction = np.sign(np.dot(midpoint - center, n)) * n
            far_point = vor.vertices[v2] + direction * radius` ** do you have a ref? Or can you say more? **