# Divide 4 coordinates into multiple points with interval of two kilometres

Tags: python, coordinates, divide

I have four coordinates and I want to divide into multiple points with an interval of 2 km distance or maximum 300 points.

Is there any possible way to do this in Python?
[I tried this but I didn’t solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573164/dividing-geographical-region-into-equal-sized-grid-and-retrieving-indexing-posit)

Comment: to divide in python, you can use `/`...

Comment: What do the 4 points represent, a line, a polygon. Are they ordered? Can you make a sketch?

Comment: @WillemHendriks it can be like a rectangle on a map (latitude ,longitude ). We want to get 300 map points (lat,long) on equal distance or with 2 km spacing.