# Strange looking Voronoi cells

Tags: voronoi, scipy-spatial, qhull

I get strange looking Voronoi cells (see center of image below), when I try to create a Voronoi diagram from a locally refined triangular mesh (white lines in image below) using the voronoi function from SciPy.

In the triangular mesh the length of longest edge is about 250.0 (not shown in the image) and the length of shortest edge is about 1.0 (see center of image below). I also added far distant points in order to intersect the Voronoi diagram with a boundary polygon. To do this, I adapted code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968838/python-finite-boundary-voronoi-cells).

I would like to use this Voronoi diagram as a mesh for simulator based on the finite volume method.

[Image of Voronoi diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roV2K.png)

I tried to add Qhull parameters, but that made it worse.