# How to make yscale uniform to display an image, despite uneven data sampling?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a 2-d array that I want to display as an image. The dimensions being Y x X(log tau vs arcsec).

The issue is the y axis (log tau) is not evenly sampled. The range of the y-axis is [1.17, -8], but there few points between 1.17 to -4 and more points between -4 and -8. Hence, using the directly imshow method will plot 1.17 to -4 in less (1/3 in my case) space and -4 to -8 more space (2/3).

As you can see in the below code, the y-ticks are uneven according to data. I want to plot a uniform linear scale on the y-axis as well.

I want some code suggestion here to squeeze/stretch points in the y-axis such that, y-ticks are equidistant.

My code:

```
## The shape of data is (log tau, arcsec) is (150, 50).
plt.imshow(data, cmap='gray', origin='lower')
plt.xticks([10, 20, 30, 40], [623.5, 623.87, 624.25, 624.63], rotation=45)
plt.yticks([50, 106, 124, 131], [-6, -4, -2, -1]) ## want some code suggestion here to squeeze / stretch points in y-axis such that, y-ticks are equidistant.
plt.gca().set_aspect(1.0 / plt.gca().get_data_ratio(), adjustable='box') ## to make square plot
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uneven data, you can replace `imshow()` with [`pcolor()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html) (or `pcolormesh()`). `pcolor()` accepts arrays of x and of y-positions as parameters. These positions mark the **borders** of each cell. Note that in each direction there will be one border more than the number of values in the 2D data (so `51` x-positions and `151` y-positions for `150x50` data).

Here is some example code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tau = np.linspace(*np.power(10, [-8, 1.17]), 151)
y = np.log(tau)
x = np.linspace(623.12, 625, 51)
data = np.random.rand(150, 50)
plt.pcolor(x, y, data, cmap='inferno')
plt.show()
```

Note that `tau` can also be used directly, with the y-axis rescaled to log-space. In any case, the ticks will be displayed as with a regular plot. Diverse [locators and/or formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) can be applied.

```py
plt.pcolor(x, tau, data, cmap='inferno')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image: uneven spacing]

Comment: Although your solution works, I am still looking for an imshow type of solution where I do not have to give extra points in X/Y. I came across a Non-Uniform image, however, after following the example given on the matplotlib page, I was not able to get it working, I have edited my question to include this code. I am grateful for your help :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at creating voronoi polygons around your points. Note that the code can look somewhat complex. E.g. [Colorize Voronoi Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515554/colorize-voronoi-diagram) and [How to color voronoi according to a color scale ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244322/how-to-color-voronoi-according-to-a-color-scale-and-the-area-of-each-cell) and the posts linked from there.

Comment: I saw the Voronoi polygons, But I doubt my case is creating polygons, it is simply displaying image with equally spaced axes and a vertically decreasing y-axis. Do you have any suggestions regarding NonUniformImage code given above?

Comment: Apparently its a bug in matplotlib, Hence pcolormesh with shading=nearest is the solution I want. Thanks