# Is there a way to crop/set a scipy Voronoi diagram?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, voronoi

I've implemented the Sibon/natural neighbor spatial interpolation using scipy's Voronoi and Shapely's polygons.
But I need to restrict my voronoi diagram as there are some polygons that are unrealistically extended way out of the domain I'm interpolating in which causes inaccuracies. Also there are non-finite regions in the Voronoi diagram for the outer points which I'd rather not have.
I often see that the Voronoi diagram is bounded in a rectangular box but I don't know how to implement it. I have tried to look for it in the scipy documentation without success.

Edit: found how to do it thanks to this post:[Colorize Voronoi Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515554/colorize-voronoi-diagram)
Thanks to anyone that took the time to read and/or write.

Comment: As a suggestion, I've found a pretty nifty way of testing the correctness of a Natural Neighbor implementation. Just last week, I posted some description of it at https://gwlucastrig.github.io/TinfourDocs/NaturalNeighborTinfourAlgorithm/index.html#is-it-accurate  Maybe this will be useful to your investigation.